# Will installing Ubuntu over pre-intalled windows remove the product key from the BIOS?

Tags: system-installation, windows, backup, bios, license

If it doesn't remove the product key can at any point of time I could get back to installing windows again if I wanted to?

Comment: No, installing Ubuntu won't overwrite a registration key for windoze. As to re-installing windoze back again, this can depend upon your countries laws.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can check on these laws?

Comment: Each country is different, consumer protection laws are what protects people in my country. Your own country may not have them, or call them something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the Windows Product Key is not kept in BIOS, but rather on a hidden partition on HDD. When installing Ubuntu it may or my not overwrite this partition - it depends on the installation method and partitioning you use.

When I install new operating system (not necessarily Ubuntu) I usually:

1. Note the product key on paper and file it for future use - search the Internet for a number utilities that can display it for you.
2. I backup the PC to be overwritten with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) using disk to image mode - in case I'd like to revert back to Windows. This also has the advantage that you can restore the the backup inside virtual machine using image to disk mode to have your original PC inside say Virtualbox or VMWare.

As for laws I cannot imagine that any license or law would preclude you from reinstalling from scratch or restoring a back-up of your PC. What would you do if your HDD would go down?

Actually you should be able to call Microsoft or your PC supplier to get information how exactly to generate restore media and Product Key in case of failed disk drive.

Comment: ["If Windows is pre-installed on a computer by an \[OEM\], the operating system is automatically activated without the need for interaction from the user. …\[The\] copy of Windows installed does not use the product key listed on the certificate of authenticity, but rather a master product key issued to OEMs…. On each boot, Windows confirms the presence of specific information stored in the BIOS by the manufacturer, ensuring the activation only remains valid on that computer, even if the product key is used on another machine."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Product_Activation)

Comment: Great. I just wrote the procedure that works for me. Among few dozens of PCs that I reinstalled, a few of them, usually coming from smaller suppliers, had no keys in BIOS, however the had small hidden partition that once removed, made reinstallation not to work. Product keys from paper and restoring with Clonezilla worked 100%. At least for me.

Comment: Another example: we had 2 desk-side servers - HP & Dell - that came with MS Windows 7, but we used them with Windows Server. After some time we replaced HDDs and installed CentOS. Last year they got a bit outdated for server use and I wanted convert it back to workstation with Windows 7. Unfortunately I had no keys and again there were no keys in BIOS - Dell Recovery media did not activate. Anyway Ubuntu works like a charm.